# Solving continuous Minimax Optimization problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, reference-request

I want to solve a linear programming minimax problem  [here](http://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/MiniMax) mathematically without using software:

$$\begin{align*}
     \text{min}\ \text{max} \quad & \{x_1,x_2,x_3\} \\
     \text{s.t.}     \quad & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15
\end{align*}$$

Or it can be written

$$\begin{align*}
    \text{min} \quad & Z \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad  & x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 15 \\
          & Z \ge x_1 \\
          & Z \ge x_2 \\
          & Z \ge x_3 \\
\end{align*}$$

I was wondering if someone could help me or provide me with good lecture notes having an explanation with examples?

**Edited**: The above problem seems solvable by inspection method, but if we consider the following problem we can't get the optimal solution by inspection (optimal solution I have obtained using the software is $x_1=0$, $x_2=0.39216$, $x_3=0.29412$, $x_4=0.31373$ and $z=-1.1765$, but I don't know how to solve it manually/mathematically, as well):
$$\begin{align*}
    \text{min} \quad & Z \\
    \text{s.t.} \quad  & x_1 + x_2 + x_3+x_4 = 1 \\
          & Z \ge x_1-3x_2 \\
          & Z \ge x_1-4x_3 \\
          & Z \ge x_1-7x_4 \\
          & Z \ge x_2-5x_4 \\
          & Z \ge x_3-5x_4 \\
          & x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\ge 0 \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! I've edited your question to use [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/38) instead of code blocks, which is our preferred style.

Comment: Please check your second formulation.  I get a different optimal solution $x=(0,20,15,16)/51$, with $z=-20/17$.

Comment: @RobPratt Yes, you are right. Edited. Thanks. But do you know how to solve it mathematically without software please?

Answer (score 7):

Although this is a linear programming problem, it can really be solved by inspection. Think about how you'd solve the problem if there were only two variables, i.e.:

$$\begin{align*}
     \text{min}\ \text{max} \quad & \{x_1,x_2\} \\
     \text{s.t.}     \quad & x_1 + x_2  = 15
\end{align*}$$

Now can you extend your approach to handle 3 variables?

Comment: Does it mean for every minmax problem, the inspection method works fine?

Comment: No, definitely not! Only that this is a very simple one.

Comment: Related: https://or.stackexchange.com/q/143/38

Answer (score 3):

The optimal solution is 15/3 for the three variables. Any other assignment is such that at least one of the variables takes a value larger than 15/3.

Answer (score 2):

For a proof that the solution $x=(5,5,5)$ is optimal, use a dual multiplier $1/3$ for each constraint:
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{3}(x_1 + x_2 + x_3) &= \frac{1}{3}\cdot 15 \\
\frac{1}{3}Z &\ge \frac{1}{3}x_1 \\
\frac{1}{3}Z &\ge \frac{1}{3}x_2 \\
\frac{1}{3}Z &\ge \frac{1}{3}x_3 \\
\end{align}
Adding these up yields $Z \ge 5$.