# Column Generation algorithm for vehicle routing problem

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization, vehicle-routing, column-generation

I want to solve a VRP with a column generation algorithm. The objective of the problem is makespan minimization. In more detail, I want to minimize the arrival time of the last vehicle in the depot. I want to know how I should write the path-based model?

In path-based models that I have ever seen for VRP, the objective was total cost minimization and all of the variables in the model were binary that corresponds to each route.
I think in my problem, I should consider a continuous non-negative variable that represents the latest arrival time of vehicles to depot. I want to know if adding this variable is correct and how will it change the column generation algorithm?

Comment: How many vehicles? Are they identical? Are you required to use them all?

Comment: There are finite number of vehicles (max K) which are identical and it is not required to use all of them.

Comment: This thread is related to your question https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/143/why-are-integer-minimax-problems-hard

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $d_i$ be the demand for customer $i\in N$, let $V=\{1,\dots,K\}$ be the set of vehicles, and let $P$ be the set of columns, where each column corresponds to a feasible subtour starting from the depot, with arc variables $x_{i,j}$ and node variables $y_i$.  Let $z$ be the makespan.
The master problem over $z$ and $\lambda$ is as follows, with dual variables in parentheses:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} &z \\
&\text{subject to} &z - \sum_{p\in P} \left(\sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} x_{i,j}^p\right) \lambda^p_v &\ge 0 &&\text{for $v\in V$} &&(\pi_v \ge 0)\\
&&\sum_{v \in V} \sum_{p\in P} y_i^p \lambda^p_v &\ge 1 &&\text{for $i\in N$}  &&(\text{$\alpha_i \ge 0$})\\
&&-\sum_{p\in P} \lambda^p_v &\ge -1 &&\text{for $v\in V$}  &&(\text{$\beta_v \ge 0$})\\
&&\lambda^p_v &\ge 0 &&\text{for $v\in V$ and $p\in P$}
\end{align}

The column generation subproblem over $x$ and $y$ for each $v\in V$ is then to minimize the reduced cost of $\lambda^p_v$.  That is, minimize
$$\pi_v \sum_{i,j} c_{i,j} x_{i,j} - \sum_{i \in N} \alpha_i y_i + \beta_v$$ subject to $(x,y)$ forming a feasible subtour starting from the depot, with $\sum_i d_i y_i \le L$, where $L$ is the capacity of each vehicle.

Because the vehicles are identical, you can use a common column pool $P$ instead of requiring a different $P_v$ for each $v\in V$.

Comment: is the pricing problem still the shortest path problem (based on time of each arc)?

Comment: Yes, you can reformulate the subproblem as elementary shortest path by splitting the depot into source and sink and moving the node weights to the arcs: $\pi_v c_{i,j}+\alpha_i$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\pi_v c_{i,j}-\alpha_i$ for the weight of arc $(i,j)$ for the elementary shortest path subproblem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the right-hand side of the second constraint must be 1 instead of d(i).

Comment: Yes, corrected just now.  The demands appear in the capacity constraint in the subproblem.

Comment: @RobPratt Does this mean you have to run $|K|$ pricing problems at each iteration (one for each $v\in V$) ?

Comment: @Kuifje The pricing objective function depends on $v$, so you have $K=|V|$ pricing problems.  But you don't necessarily have to solve all of them each time.  You can return to the master as soon as you find one negative-reduced cost column.

Comment: Thanks for your insight